# nested json access by jquery. Nested array json i want to acess

Tags: jquery, json

```js
{
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "Id": 2,
                "Name": "name",
                "city": "Delhi",
                "location": "Anand Vihar",
                "landmark": null,
                "pincode": 100221,
                "profilePic": null,
                "emailId": "email@gmail.com",
                "membershipName": null
            ][
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "Name": "name",
                    "city": "Delhi",
                    "location": "Anand Vihar",
                    "landmark": null,
                    "pincode": 100221,
                    "profilePic": null,
                    "emailId": "email@gmail.com",
                    "membershipName": null
                ]
            ]
        }
```

I have above format of json. please help me to acess from jquery.

Comment: Your JSON format was wrong.

Comment: the `json` string is not valid, use jsonlint.com to test and fix.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in above comments first construct `proper json data`.some thing like below,then iterate through it to process each.to test json data visite:http://json.parser.online.fr/

```
<script>
var json='{"data": [[{"Id": 2,"Name": "name","city": "Delhi","location": "Anand Vihar","landmark": null,"pincode": 100221,"profilePic": null,"emailId": "email@gmail.com","membershipName": null},{"Id": 2,"Name": "name","city": "Delhi","location": "Anand Vihar","landmark": null,"pincode": 100221,"profilePic": null,"emailId": "email@gmail.com","membershipName": null}]]}';

                var json=JSON.parse(json);

     for(x in json['data'][0]){//you can use each also.
         console.log(json['data'][0][x]);//it will log each data set get the attributes to use
     }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Please see follow link](https://jsfiddle.net/852gin/11p7e3z6/3/)

```
    var uData =data.data;           
for(var i in uData)
   { 
       var rd = $('<tr class=""></tr>');
       var o=uData[i];
       for(var j in o)
       {
           rd.append('<td>'+o[j]+'</td>');
           $('#example').append(rd);
       }
   }
```

Be careful with JSON-array structure